# diff continue on error

Tags: linux, shell, compare, diff

I can't get diff to ignore file system errors and continue the directory comparison.

I run a diff -r on two very similar directories with broken files in it. How can I get a complete comparison, is there another way, diff exits with an Input/output error

Comment: Are you able to copy the non-damaged files to a healthy location? If yes, just compare with the copy.

Answer (score 3):

you probably can't stop diff exiting (unless you change & recompile the source), but I'd look into using 'find':

```
find . -type f -exec diff {} ../other/folder/{} \;
```

The 'find' command here returns a list of filenames and passes them to 'diff' one at a time for comparison. The path of the current file is represented by {}